# Store the Jquery DataTable applied filters in the url to be copied

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using jquery datatables for server side processing I fetch the orders from db and use search and pagination that is working great.

Now I want to show the searchfilter and pagesizes and such as dropdown for ordercountry on the browser whenever user applies the filter.

I can user two HttpGet and HttpPost methods LoadOrderData in asp.net mvc and add replace the browser url before an ajax call made so that user will be able to copy and paste on another tab so that httpGet method will be called:

Here is the JS code :

```
"ajax": {
        "url": '/controller/LoadData',
        "type": "POST",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "dataType": "json",
        "data": function (d) {

            var search = $('#orderList_filter input[type="search"]').val();

            // Append the filter and search parameters to the URL
            var url = '/Controller/LoadData?searchValue=' + encodeURIComponent(search);

            // Update the browser URL
            window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
            
            return JSON.stringify(d);
        }
    },
```

Here are the methods in MVC:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("LoadData");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LoadData(string filter, string searchValue)
    {
        var orderData = await GetOrdersData(searchValue)
        return View("Index",orderData);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LoadOrdersData(JsonRequestForDataTable model)
    {
    }
```

please suggest the best way to do it.